# Configuração Firestore - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Referente a configuração [FireStore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)  em projetos já existentes. [ANDROID]

Tentei incluir e configurar de acordo com o material de apoio e não da certo.

Da erro ao adicionar as dependências no Gradle-App.

Dependência que está no material do Firebase.
**compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.6'**

obs: Tentei colocar como 10.2.6, e também tentei atualizar todas as dependências para a mesma versão do FireStore. Nada funcionou.

Atualmente tenho as versões 10.2.6 dos serviços Firebase.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
```

Erro:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6.
```

Obs:

Verifiquei as atualizações do PlayService e Repositorio. E tambem verifiquei sobre as dependências no Gradle:

**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'**

Comment: Então Tiago, se você atualiza um você terá que atualizar todas as dependencias relacionadas ao Google Services

Comment: Eu tentei, e da o mesmo erro. Todas essas que tem 10.2.6 eu coloquei para 11.0.6, e da o mesmo erro. Lá no Firebase descreve que tem as versões 10.2.6, nem aparece a 11.0.6. Aí não sei o que pode ser. @Matheus

Comment: Então, vocÊ terá qu e fazer uma ampla busca no seu projeto, tinha uma época que eu estava com o mesmo problema e quebrei a cabeça pra arrumar, mas era por causa de uma SDK externa que tinha uma versão diferente para a qual eu queria atualizar.

Comment: Sim. Eu já migrei algumas vezes. E nunca deu problema e sim é preciso alterar todas as dependências. O problema está especificamente no FireStore. Tentei novamente e renomeando todas para a mesma versao deu o seguinte: Error: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.2.6.  @Matheus

Comment: Eu estava fazendo errado!! Alterei tudo de novo e deu certo!! Obrigado!!! @Matheus

Comment: Funcionou ?Que ótimo =)